# I can't extract zip split file in linux ubuntu only in windows

Tags: php, linux, split, zip, extract

I have an application that allows user to download files as zip. If the files zip is greater than 5mb then i split it, so the users could download it by parts.

Here's how the modal look:

[image]

When i extract it in Windows OS it worked. But in linux (Ubuntu) it doesn't.

It will only work if i type this first in the terminal where the split parts is located:

```
# zip -F filename.zip --out newFileName.zip
```

Here's the code when i split the zip file:

```
shell_exec('zip tempFile.zip --out filename_part.zip -s 2m');
```

Here's how the split files looks:
[image]

**Summary:**

The split files can only be extracted in windows OS without typing in the terminal. What i want is to right click and extract it in linux same in windows.

Comment: I recall that recent versions of 7zip (7za) will handle multi-part zip archives better than unzip does on Linux.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. thnx i will try it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i got it. here's the source https://superuser.com/questions/184557/how-to-create-multipart-7zip-file-in-linux